# need help to open stackoverflow in my intranet

Tags: firewall, webproxy

I have problem when i open www.stackoverflow.com on my intranet which is protected by firewall, open very slow and only text appears, no image or format render on browser.

my admin says that he has done setting in web blocker to allow this site, but if this site open any other url then i have to tell him then he will unblock that url,

kindly  suggest me what settings is required in firewall to open this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to also add exceptions for `cdn.sstatic.net` and `ajax.googleapis.com`